# PHP/SQLite Security

Tags: php, sqlite

I am very new to the whole PHP/SQLite security game; I have no idea how to protect against injection attacks, PHP_SELF based threats, and the like. Can someone go over my 55-line sign in page and point out any security holes I might have? I would really appreciate it.

```
<?php
// Begin Redirector ******************************************************************************************
if (isset($_COOKIE["session"])) { header("location:http://pagesnap.tk/"); }
// End Redirector ******************************************************************************************

else
{
?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sign In - PageSnap</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>PageSnap</h1>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username "/>
                <br />
                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input name="signin" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php
    if ($_POST["signin"]) // If Form Is Submitted
    {
        // Variables
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $password = hash("sha512", $password);

        // Database Connection
        $database = new PDO("sqlite:database.sqlite");

        // Entry Finder
        $result = $database -> query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

        // Success
        if ($result -> fetchColumn() > 0)
        {
            $id = $database -> query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
            $id = $id -> fetchColumn();
            setcookie("session", "$id", time()+3600);
            header("location:http://pagesnap.tk/");
        }

        // Failure (Entry Not Found)
        else
        {
            echo "You have entered your username or password incorrectly.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, the URL of my site is pagesnap.tk, if you want to try it out.

Comment: Never trust user submitted information.  Blindly pushing information into your queries like that is *exactly* how you get SQL Injections.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: at least you are using pdo, but you need to bind your variables.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to codereview?

Answer (score -1):

1. you should filter all input using ctype_* or filter_var functions:

   ```
    if( ctype_alnum( $_POST["username"]  )  ) {

         $username = $_POST["username"];

    } else {

        //error

    }
   ```

   do for all other inputs
2. you should be using prepared statements
3. you should be using bound parameters
4. you should escape all output in this case:

   ```
        setcookie("session", htmlentities( $id ), time()+3600);
   ```